# Datatable server-side remember checkbox "selected"

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have datatable server-side in modal(popup) to select item by select checkbox in item row.

But when i change page, sorting, and search other item, my selected item in checkbox always reset or reload.

Did datatable server-side can remember my selected checkbox? And if can, how to implement it in my case?

Comment: Try add 'stateSave': true to your datatable and in reload table.DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);

Comment: Hay @rad1, thanks for suggest. It's not work and table still reload, there's more sugget? It's really confused.

Comment: Add code to your question

Answer (score 4):

Although it's undocumented but [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option only works in client-side processing mode as far as I know.

Please see [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) extension that provides universal solution for working with checkboxes in a table in both client-side and server-side processing modes.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'processing': true,
   'serverSide': true,
   'ajax': '/your/script',
   'columnDefs': [
      {
        'targets': 0,
        'checkboxes': true
      }
   ],
   'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to implement it yourself without a plug-in, see [jQuery DataTables: Row selection using checkboxes](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) article.

Comment: I tried checkboxes with serverside processing using https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/server-side/server-side-processing/ but whenever I checked any checkbox "select all" checkbox is marked as selected or ticked causes move to another page shows all selected records.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Do you have some example of server-side solution with checkboxes which are outside of table, please? Thanks

Comment: @culter, not sure what you mean? Do you have an example? Share the link if you have posted a question on SO.

Comment: Hi, Gyrocode, your example has checkboxes in front of every row, I needed to filter data in my table with checkboxes. E.g. when you click on one of the checkboxes, only rows with status 1 from colunn 3 are displayed and so on. But few days ago I was able to make it working. Anyway, thanks for reply.